# Stable Diffusion использует процессор вместо видеокарты

Tags: python, pytorch

При установке и запуске .bat файла консоль пишет, что не установлены драйверы NVIDIA, хотя у меня видеокарта от AMD и есть драйверы на неё. Далее в терминале выводится ошибка:

```
 "Torch is not able to use GPU"
```

Предлагает ввести в .bat файл в строчку с "set COMMANDLINE_ARGS" аргумент --skip-torch-cuda-test, после чего нейросеть запускается и работает. Но при попытке сгенерировать изображение нагружается процессор вместо видеокарты, несмотря на то, что в настройках выставлена генерация через видеокарту. [image: настройки Stable Diffusion]
Сверху видно, что я выбрал GPU, а не процессор.

[image: начало генерации, нагрузка на процесор, вместо видеокарты]

[image: нагрузка на видеокарту во время генерации]

Однако нагрузка на мои комплектующие показывает обратное.

Продублирую компоненты на всякий случай:
Процессор: Intel Core-i3 8100;
Видеокарта: AMD Radeon RX 580 8Gb.

Comment: А разве Torch умеет работать с картами AMD? В том то и дело, что все нейросетевые библиотеки работают сугубо с Nvidia через CUDA. Хотя я давно не следил и может ситуация поменялась, но вообще долгое время было вот так. AMD можно для игр было использовать, но не для нейросеток.

Answer (score 2):

Библиотеки глубокого машинного обучения, в частности PyTorch, в которой написан Stable Diffusion, используют карты NVIDIA, именно под них пишется практически весь софт с организацией нейросетевых вычислений на GPU. Поэтому либо работа на CPU, либо замена видеокарты на NVIDIA (сразу узнавайте объем необходимой видеопамяти, современные нейросети очень прожорливы).

Answer (score 0):

не туда смотришь. там скорее всего всё нормально грузится[image: выставь параметр CUDA]